# Error when i'm going to start slurm in node

Tags: centos7, slurm

I'm preparing a cluster with personal machine, I mount Centos 7 in the server and I'm trying to start the slurm clients but when I typed this command:

```
pdsh -w n[00-09] systemctl start slurmd
```

I had this error:

```
n07: Job for slurmd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status slurmd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
pdsh@localhost: n07: ssh exited with exit code 1
```

I had that message for all the nodes.

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status slurmd.service -l 

● slurmd.service - Slurm node daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/slurmd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-12-22 18:27:30 CST; 27min ago
  Process: 1589 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/slurmd $SLURMD_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Dec 22 18:27:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Slurm node daemon...
Dec 22 18:27:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: slurmd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Dec 22 18:27:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Slurm node daemon.
Dec 22 18:27:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit slurmd.service entered failed state.
Dec 22 18:27:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: slurmd.service failed.
```

This is the slurm.conf file:

```
ClusterName=linux
ControlMachine=localhost
#ControlAddr=
#BackupController=
#BackupAddr=
#
SlurmUser=slurm
#SlurmdUser=root
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPort=6818
AuthType=auth/munge
#JobCredentialPrivateKey=
#JobCredentialPublicCertificate=
StateSaveLocation=/var/spool/slurm/ctld
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurm/d
SwitchType=switch/none
MpiDefault=none
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurmctld.pid
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid
ProctrackType=proctrack/pgid
#PluginDir=
#FirstJobId=
#MaxJobCount=
#PlugStackConfig=
#PropagatePrioProcess=
#PropagateResourceLimits=
#PropagateResourceLimitsExcept=
#Prolog=
#Epilog=
#SrunProlog=
#SrunEpilog=
#TaskProlog=
#TaskEpilog=
#TaskPlugin=
#TrackWCKey=no
#TreeWidth=50
#TmpFS=
#UsePAM=
#
#TIMERS

SlurmctldTimeout=300
SlurmdTimeout=300
InactiveLimit=0
MinJobAge=300
KillWait=30
Waittime=0
#
#SCHEDULING

SchedulerType=sched/backfill
#SchedulerAuth=
#SelectType=select/linear
FastSchedule=1
#PriorityType=priority/multifactor
#PriorityDecayHalfLife=14-0
#PriorityUsageResetPeriod=14-0
#PriorityWeightFairshare=100000
#PriorityWeightAge=1000
#PriorityWeightPartition=10000
#PriorityWeightJobSize=1000
#PriorityMaxAge=1-0
#
#LOGGING
SlurmctldDebug=3
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=3
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurmd.log
JobCompType=jobcomp/none
#JobCompLoc=
#
#ACCOUNTING                                                                              #JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/linux                                                   #JobAcctGatherFrequency=30                                                                #                                                                                         #AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/slurmdbd                                        #AccountingStorageHost=                                                                   #AccountingStorageLoc=                                                                    #AccountingStoragePass=                                                                   #AccountingStorageUser=                                                                   #                                                                                         #COMPUTE NODES                                                                           # OpenHPC default configuration                                                           TaskPlugin=task/affinity                                                                  PropagateResourceLimitsExcept=MEMLOCK                                                     AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/filetxt                                          Epilog=/etc/slurm/slurm.epilog.clean                                                      NodeName=n[00-09] Sockets=1 CoresPerSocket=6 ThreadsPerCore=2 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=normal Nodes=n[00-09] Default=YES MaxTime=24:00:00 State=UP
ReturnToService=1
```

The control machine was set by hostname -s

Comment: Can you share the output of `systemctl show slurmd` and also of `slurmd -Dvvv` ?

Comment: @damienfrancois, the output of  `slurmd -Dvvv` is: bash: slurmd: command not found... and  `systemctl show slurmd` is too long, what lines do you want to see?? I think that the problem is in the slurm.conf